# XSLT - Add Hyphen to Attribute values

Tags: xml, xslt

New to XSLT and trying to insert a hyphen after specific attributes.

XML source example:

```
    <TASK CHAPNBR="12" SECTNBR="13" SUBJNBR="01" FUNC="130" SEQ="803">

    @CHAPNBR will always contain two digits
    @SECTNBR will always contain two digits
    @SUBJNBR will always contain two digits
    @FUNC will always contain three digits.
```

No hyphen inserted after SEQ.
The attribute names will never change but the numeric values can/will.

Only need to insert a hyphen after the following attributes:

```
    @CHAPNBR, @SECTNBR, @SUBJNBR, @FUNC
```

My current XSLT output does this:

```
    <TASK>12 13 01 130 803</TASK>
```

Need it to do this:

```
    <TASK>12-13-01-130-803</TASK>
```

Extremely grateful for any suggestions/thoughts!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `<xsl:template match="TASK"><xsl:copy><xsl:value-of select="concat(@CHAPNBR, '-', @SECTNBR, '-', @SUBJNBR, '-', @FUNC, '-', @SEQ)"/></xsl:copy></xsl:template>`.

Comment: Thank you SO much!  Just awesome and I've been banging my head on this for too long, was making it more complicated then it needed to be!  Thanks again - truly appreciate your time and assistance! :)